# Can not clear the JList Java

Tags: swing, jlist

I am **using NETBEANS 7** . I have on JList in my project. Here is my code

```
private void dateChooserSelectedDatePropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                                       
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
    listSerialNo = new JList(model);

    UpdatePurchase updatePurchase = new UpdatePurchase();
    Vector<String> serialNo = new Vector<String>();
    serialNo = updatePurchase.getSerialNo(date);
    if(serialNo.size()>0){
        listSerialNo.setListData(serialNo);
    }
    else{

        model.clear();
        this.resetFields();
    }
}
```

If I write above code then list doesn't show any thing & its not clearing the JList. But If I remove

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
listSerialNo = new JList(model);
```

then list populates with some data from vector serialNo.

My problem:

1. I want to clear the contents of list if date value changed & no records are present for selected date.
2. Also I want to clear the contents of list when I click "Reset" button on my form.

Basically I can not clear the contents of jList. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this-

```
listSerialNo.setListData(new Vector());
```

This will re-set the list data with a empty vector object.

so all the list data will be removed.

Comment: listSerialNo.setListData(new String[0]) works also and is probably preferred nowadays since Vector is an "obsolete" JDK class.

Answer (score 1):

The method `setListData` actually replaces the data model of your `JList`. Thus you do not clear the current list model but the initially assigned (which is no longer under use). Therefore, do not use `setListData` but add the new elements directly to your original model.

Comment: I change line to listSerialNo.getModel().clear(); but it gives me error that "can not find method clear()". 
I don't know whats happing...

Comment: @appDev sorry, my fault. The model does not have a clear method at all. Then you'll have to go with the second method or reset the model completely.

Comment: Can you tell what exactly I am supposed to do. Because I am new to java developer. I am totally confused with this thing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already have an JList component added which is visible. In your code you create a new one while overriding the field containing the old one. Therefore you lost the 'connection' to the old (and visible) one. By updating the new one nothing visible will change as you update the wrong one.

By removing those 2 lines, you are not creating a new JList anymore and are updating the correct one.

So why not just remove those 2 lines as that seems to work according to your post.

Comment: For the *solution* you'd better take a look at the answer of Howard as it is better.

Comment: Maybe it is a mixture of both our answers. I didn't recognize that OP is creating a new `JList` every time. So this may also be a possible source of trouble.